# How to sum all the columns in R and return a new row at the bottom with the total sum

Tags: r

I currently have a dataframe in R named as df. The df looks something like this:

> con       A      B       C         D
>
> ab          24   34      2     16
>
> ba        47   12     23     21
>
> cd        23    1    2       32

Now, i want the sum of all the rows(ab,ba,cd...n) in each column (A,B,C,D....n) and add or append one row at the bottom with all total values. After the sum, the data should look something like this:

> con       A      B       C         D
>
> ab          24   34      2     16
>
> ba        47   12     23     21
>
> cd        23    1    2       32
>
> sum      94    47   27    69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `add_margins` from `base R` after converting the numeric columns to a matrix and changing the row names as 'con' column

```
addmargins(`row.names<-`(as.matrix(df1[-1]), df1$con), 1)
#     A  B  C  D
#ab  24 34  2 16
#ba  47 12 23 21
#cd  23  1  2 32
#Sum 94 47 27 69
```

---

or with `adorn_totals` from `janitor`

```
library(janitor)
df1 %>% 
    adorn_totals(name = 'Sum')
#  con  A  B  C  D
#  ab 24 34  2 16
#  ba 47 12 23 21
#  cd 23  1  2 32
# Sum 94 47 27 69
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(con = c("ab", "ba", "cd"), A = c(24L, 47L, 23L
), B = c(34L, 12L, 1L), C = c(2L, 23L, 2L), D = c(16L, 21L, 32L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```